# Voice to text translator raspberry pi

Tags: text, raspberry-pi, voice-recording

Hi Im new to programming for Raspberry pi, but i have decided to make a "Voice to text translator" using the Raspberry pi.

So here is what it should do step by step:

1. press a button to start.
2. speak to the device via a plugged in microphone.
3. The device will now take the voice and convert it to a text
   document.
4. Save it to the SD card.
5. Then press a button to stop.

So what i would like to know is, if this has already been made (I could not find any, for Raspberry pi)
and if this is even possible?

And thanks for the help by the way! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check out jasper](http://jasperproject.github.io/) I was very impressed that a Raspberry Pi could do such a good job. It only messed up once for me (I said 'mayonnaise' and it put 'many')  It is based on [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/).